# Añadir nuevas filas ó columnas a matriz numpy

Tags: python, arraylist, numpy

Estoy trabajando con matrices y arrays numpy y necesito una manera elegante de añadir filas o columnas al final de la matriz.
También hacer lo mismo con arrays 1-Dimensión.

P. Ejemplo, si mi matriz tiene la forma:

```
0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
```

Insertar una fila = xxxx tal que quedase así:

```
0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
x x x x
```

O una columna = xxxx t. q:

```
0 0 1 1 x
1 0 0 1 x
0 1 1 0 x
1 0 0 0 x
```

De la misma forma si tengo un array 1-D, como insertar a modo de "push" un nuevo valor t. q si array= [1,2,3,4] -/- valor = x -> array tras insertar queda:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,x]
```

Nota, las "X" representan el mismo tipo con el que se trabaja (Ints, etc), lo que quiero es saber hacer esto de manera elegante con NumPy ya que los elementos con los que estoy trabajando son matrices y arrays numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En muchos lenguajes se emplea para definir un arreglo matricial la forma `(Fila, Columnas)`, en tal sentido se hace lo siguiente:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((4,3))

print(a)
# [[0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0.]]   

print(a.shape)
# (4, 3) # dimensiones de matriz en forma de tupla


print(np.insert(a, a.shape[0], np.array((20, 20, 20)), 0)) # 0 o tambien axis=0
# se agrega a la ultima fila a.shape[0]
# para denotar fila se usa cero (0) axis = 0
# [[ 0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.]
#  [20. 20. 20.]]


print(np.insert(a, a.shape[1], np.array((10, 10, 10, 10)), 1)) # 1 o tambien axis=1
# se agrega a la ultima columna a.shape[1]
# para denotar columna se usa uno (1) axis = 1
# [[ 0.  0.  0. 10.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0. 10.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0. 10.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0. 10.]]
```

En el caso del array puede hacerse lo siguiente

```
array = np.array([10, 20, 30])

print(np.append(array, 40))    
print(np.append(array, [40]))
print(np.append(array, [40], 0))
print(np.append(array, [40], axis=0))

# cualquiera de las cuatro expresiones es equivalente
# [10 20 30 40]

# Esto permite también agregar listas como elementos
print(np.append(array, [40,50]))
# [10 20 30 40 50]
```

La documentación de [numpy.insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) y [numpy.append](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_append.htm) (ambas en inglés)

Comment: Hola, perdon por responder tan tarde, pero he estado haciendo pruebas y trabajo con dtype=np.uint8, y para ese tipo salta excepcion la funcion insert porque intenta parsearlo a int y no puede o algo así, como habría que llamar a insert para un tipo cualquiera que no sean estandares como int o float asecas? "TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc add output from dtype('int32') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'"

Comment: Hola @AlfonsoSoriaMuñoz, estoy leyendo lo que has escrito pero a menos que proveas datos y que estás haciendo específicamente, estaría entrando al terreno de la especulación y no podría ayudarte adecuadamente, sugiero que plantees una nueva pregunta, así podrás recibir varias perspectivas y enfoques para resolver esta cosa puntual que acotas. No obstante  se puede especificar en el array el tipo de dato por ejemplo `a=np.insert(a, a.shape[0], np.array((20.12, 20.5, 21.7), dtype=np.float64), 0)` y al impirmir `a` ya no tendrás problemas en que se vea la parte decimal

Comment: El caso sería similar con `a=np.insert(a, a.shape[0], np.array((20.12, 20.5, 21.7), dtype=np.uint8), 0)` incluso hay un post acá en *[numpy uint8 pixel wrapping solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547557/numpy-uint8-pixel-wrapping-solution)* dónde mencionan lo que expones, pero con otro tipo de operaciones. Como dije inicialmente, te sugiero si ves conveniente, que formules una nueva pregunta para que se incluya los datos y como lo has intentado, tratando de ser especifico para tener una mejor idea de la situación y se te pueda ayudar mejor.

Comment: el problema simplemente es que opero con np.uint8 y esa operacion(insert) intenta castear a un tipo estandar y falla, voy a ver como castear a int tanto la matriz como los arrays y despues recastear (porque si trabajo con ints paso de tener en memoria de 20 megas a 80 o 160 megas(dependiendo de la arquitectura del pc) y quiero optimizar ese tipo de datos ya que en realidad practicamente uso uint8 porque representan 3 estados, y la matriz puede crecer mucho más de lo que es ahora (si ahora sera de 10.000x5000, en un futuro puede ser bastante mayor...)

Comment: de todas formas veo que usando int8 no me da problemas la operacion insert, así que puedo trabajar tambien con ese tipo de datos y ahorrarme tanta tontería >_<